# How can I run cypress case by string code?

Tags: cypress

cypress how to run string code case， don't need entities file，like this:

```js
    cypress.run(`
        describe('My First Test', () => {
            it('Does not do much!', () => {
                expect(true).to.equal(false)
             })
         })`
     )
```

Comment: Please add more details on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Because my test case is stored in the database, I want to execute the string case obtained from the database instead of executing the *.spec.js